# trying to obtain a first name in the path after first back slash

Tags: java

I want to display the first folder name from the path.
/mnt/sdcard/Videos/lk.jpeg, I want to display  **mnt** string. in java

```
/mnt/sdcard/Videos/lk.jpeg--> **mnt**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "/mnt/sdcard/Videos/lk.jpeg";
System.out.println(str.split("/")[1]);
```

Try this out. This is a poor question. But maybe the asker can be a newbie.

Comment: Are you using the exact same code I pasted here. There would be five elements in the array...Then how will it throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. If you are using some other string then enclose the statements with this condition. if(str.split("/").length > 1)

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` on `/` and use `[1]` element from result array.

Comment: An example of `split` is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: @downvoter Any problems with this approach?

Comment: What is happening here?.  @Pshemo is correct.. arr[0] will contain an empty String.. arr[1] will have the actual value..

Comment: @OlegS. "*[1] element from result array*" isn't `[index]` + `array` clear enough? Should I really make it more clear by writing `array[index]`?

Comment: Ok, fair enough, my bad -- voted back up

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) or you can use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Note that the split() result should be checked for live usage (e.g. if it has at least two elements).

```
String desired = "/mnt/sdcard/foo".split("/")[1];
```